# Parse cloud code many-to-many relation is not working

Tags: parse-platform, many-to-many, relation

I have an Event table and it has a column called "attendees" which is a Relation type to _User [many to many].

I am writing a custom cloud function to incremenet a "headCount" column and also to add a _User to the Event.attendees Relation. It doesn't seem to work. I have identified that I have a User object and an Event object but the relation.add() function is *not* adding a User to the Relation.

Any ideas?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("joinEvent", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Event");
    query.get(request.params.eventId, {
        success: function(event) {
            console.error("Joining event");
            var headCount = parseInt(event.get("headCount"));
            var quota = parseInt(event.get("quota"));
            if (headCount < quota) {
                event.set("headCount", ++headCount);
                event.save();
                // attach to the event 
                console.error(request.user);
                var relation = event.relation("attendees");
                relation.add(request.user);
                event.save();
                response.success();
            } else {
                response.error("Sorry, this event is full.");
            }
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            response.error(error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens if you add a success callback to event.save()? For example, event.save(null, { success: function(gameScore) { /* do something after successfully saved */ }, error: function(gameScore, error) { console.log('142 error saving:' + JSON.stringify(error)); } });

Comment: Problem was that in my preSave() I have a date verification that was being executed always (as in it was checking that the time of the Event was in the future) this was causing it to silently not save the event... strange!

Comment: Thanks @andreas this is solved?